# Lower bounds on the rank of a unimodular lattice, given the binlinear pairing of a subset of basis vectors

Tags: lattices, quadratic-forms, lattice-theory, integral-quadratic-forms

I have some questions on lower bounds on the rank of unimodular lattices given the bilinear pairing of a subset of its basis is known.

1. Let $\Lambda$ be an odd, unimodular matrix of signature $(1,T)$. In particular, there exists a basis in which the bilinear form $B$ of the lattice is given by
   \begin{equation}
   B  = \rm diag(1,-1,\cdots,-1) \,.
   \end{equation}
   Now let us assume that there exists $k$ mutually orthogonal lattice vectors $x_1,\cdots,x_k$ with norm $-n < -1$, i.e.,
   \begin{equation}
   x_i \cdot x_j = -n \delta_{ij} \,,
   \end{equation}
   that are further assumed to be elements of a basis of the lattice $\Lambda$. Given the existence of these vectors, how big does $T$ have to be to accommodate them? In other words, what is the lower bound $b(n,k)$ on $T$?
2. There are some trivial bounds we can get. For example,
   \begin{equation}
   b(n,k) \geq k \,.
   \end{equation}
   Also, it is clear that
   \begin{equation}
   b(n,k) \leq nk \,.
   \end{equation}
   Can we get a tighter range or better lower-bounds on $b(n,k)$? For example, it can be shown that
   \begin{equation}
   b(n,k) \geq 2k \,.
   \end{equation}
   Can one do better? (One might mistakenly think that $b(m^2,k)=k < 2k$, but the assumption is that $\{ x_i : i =1,\cdots, k \}$ is a subset of the basis of the lattice. Hence, for example, $b(4,1) = 3$, rather than $1$.)
3. Can one find better linear lower-bounds? In other words, does there exist a number $\alpha_n >2$ such that
   \begin{equation}
   b(n,k) \geq \alpha_n k +\beta
   \end{equation}
   for some constant $\beta$?
4. Now let us assume there exist $k$ mutually orthogonal basis vectors $x_1, \cdots, x_k$ of $\Lambda$, all of which have negative norms, i.e.,
   \begin{equation}
   (x_i \cdot x_j) = {\rm diag} (-n_1, \cdots , -n_k) \,,
   \end{equation}
   with $n_i > 1$. What is the smallest allowed value $b(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$ for $T$ in this case?
5. Can one imagine there being good linear bound(s)
   \begin{equation}
   b(n_1,\cdots,n_k) \geq \gamma_{n_1} + \cdots + \gamma_{n_k} +\beta
   \end{equation}
   for some $\beta$ in this more generalized case as well? In other words, does there exist $\gamma_n >1$ for each $n$ that gives such linear bounds?
6. I have only been able to get some very loose bounds using only very elementary tools so far. Where should I look to learn methods that can be used to effectively tackle with problems of this sort?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b(n,k)\ge2k$ is a pretty good bound. You definitely have $b(n,k)\le2k+\mathrm{const}$ with a constant not very large (something like at most $8$, but you can make it better depending on $kn\bmod8$). Here is the argument.

The situation with **even** form is somewhat simpler and everything follows from

> MR0525944 (80j:10031) 
>   Nikulin, V. V.
>   Integer symmetric bilinear forms and some of their geometric applications. (Russian)
>   Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 43 (1979), no. 1, 111–177, 238.
>   10C05 (14G30 14J17 14J25 57M99 57R45 58C27)

(There is an English translation.)

**Edit:** Here is a proof of the fact that $2k+8$ is enough. (All refs are to the above paper.) It suffices to construct an odd lattice $T$ (the prospective orthogonal complement) with inertia indices $(1,\sigma_-)$ and discriminant $k\langle\frac1n\rangle$, cf. Proposition 1.6.1 (where discriminant are considered with bilinear forms only, disregarding the quadratic form). Let $r=1+\sigma_-$ be the rank. We start with an **even** lattice $T$, see Theorem 1.10.1. (If $n$ is even, we can play with recovering the quadratic discriminant form; if $n$ is odd, it is unique.) Since signature $\bmod 8$ is determined by the discriminant form (Brown invariant), we may have to add up to $7$ to $\sigma_-$ to make it right. Next, since the length of the discriminant form is $k$, Nikulin's theorem will guarantee the existence (provided that the signature is right) whenever $r>k$. Thus, we can always find an **even** lattice $T$ of rank at most $k+7$. Now, just add $[-1]$ to make it odd (of rank at most $k+8$). By Proposition 1.6.1, there is a primitive extension of your lattice $S$ to a unimodular lattice such that $S^\perp\cong T\oplus[-1]$.

If you are fighting for every single unit, one can compute more precisely the Brown invariant (which depends on $k$ and the prime factors of $n$), there is no need in $[-1]$ if $n$ is odd, and, if $n$ is even, one can probably try to avoid that $[-1]$ by a "wrong" gluing of the two lattice (choosing an anti-isometry of the bilinear forms which is not an anti-isometry of quadratic ones). However, constructing an odd form $T$ in the first place would probably give a better result; unfortunately, I do not know any existence theorems for this case. And, as you've correctly noticed yourself, there is no way to improve that more than by $8$ :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm surprised at your claim that $b(n,k) \leq 2k + {\rm const}$---can you explain this in more detail? I expected $\alpha_n$ to be larger than $2$ for, say, $n=12$. Note that I've fixed the signature of the lattice to be $(1,T)$ and assumed that the lattice is odd.

Comment: I will try to put a short proof to the answer.

Comment: Accidentally, the answer to your Question 5 is also $\le2k+8$, with the same proof :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is crystal clear now. :)

Comment: @D.S.Park: Just one last addition: sometimes, you have to add $8$ to get the signature right **and** satisfy the hypothesis of Nikulin's theorem (without computing the determinant for $\mathrm{length}=\mathrm{rank}$). On the other hand, there's no need to add $[-1]$: if $n$ is odd, the result is odd automatically, if $n$ is even, you take the quadratic extension $\langle(n+1)/n\rangle$ rather than $\langle1/n\rangle$, so the **quadratic** forms are not identified via an anti-isomorphism and the ambient lattice is still odd. Now, everything seems taken care of, and it's still $2k+8$ :)